# C++ : CRTP destructor?

Tags: c++, inheritance, crtp

On a project, I have the following problem :

I have a very simple inheritance scheme (I need inheritance and not composition) :

class Base

-> class DerivedA

-> class DerivedB

-> class DerivedC

A, B and C derive from Base and that's all.
So now I have 2 choices :

public inheritance with virtuality

private inheritance without virtuality

For some optimization reasons (I need a lot of inlining) I don't want virtuality ... and I don't want private inheritance. I think that the only option that remains is CRTP. But the base class have like 300 functions and implementing CRTP in it will be a real pain.

So I wonder if the following solution is valid : I use CRTP only in the destructor of the base class :

```
template<class TCRTP> class Base
{
    ~Base() {delete static_cast<TCRTP*>(this);}
}
```

where TCRTP will be DerivedA, B or C and I do public inheritance.
Is it perfectly ok, or problematic ?

Thank you very much.

Comment: I don't understand why you don't use plain public inheritance "without virtuality" if you don't need that.

Comment: That doesn't even begin to make sense. You can't delete references, and you can almost never say `delete this` in a useful way. Can you post a small, representative example of your actual problem?

Comment: I've made a mistake in the original code.

Comment: You say you don't need composition, but private inheritance is just a form of composition. It doesn't make sense to speak of an inheritance hierarchy when you have private inheritance.

Comment: a base class with 300 functions? how about doing some serious refactoring?

Comment: 95% of these functions are inline, and around 30% of them are overloeded operators for scalar and array types.

Comment: @Vincent: that shouldn't be an excuse. You couldn't templatize those operators? and that still leaves 200 non-operator functions.

Comment: if you have no problem with 300 few-liners, what is then the problem of writing another 300 one-line passthrough functions for the CRTP derived classes?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your destructor is definitely wrong. The destructor of a class does not and must not `delete` the memory for the object.

What's your objection to public inheritance without virtual functions? There are (at least) a couple of ways to prevent someone accidentally deleting a derived object through a base pointer. One is to make the base destructor `protected`.

Another is to stuff dynamically-allocated instances of the derived class straight into a `shared_ptr`. This can even be a `shared_ptr<Base>`:

```
std::shared_ptr<Base> foo(new DerivedA(...));
```

Because `shared_ptr` has a template constructor that captures the type of its argument, the `Base*` pointer will be converted to `DerivedA*` in the deleter function associated with the `shared_ptr`, and hence deleted correctly. Nobody should ever be so daft as to try to extract a pointer out of a `shared_ptr` and delete it as `Base*`.

Of course if you have no virtual functions, then the trick is only really useful when the only difference between the derived classes is what they set up in their constructors. Otherwise you'll end up needing to downcast the `Base*` pointer from the `shared_ptr`, in which case you should have used a `shared_ptr<DerivedA>` to begin with.

Answer (score 1):

I could see using code like inside the implementation of `IUnknown::Release`, but never in a destructor.  The `Base` destructor only runs after the derived object has been destroyed, trying to `delete` the derived object at that point is undefined behavior.  I'm pretty sure you'd get infinite recursion in that particular case.